# How can I create a dynamic Matrix inside a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I have a function where a `n` parameter is handed and a list of values is calculated inside of it. I then need to solve a linear system of equations that require me to construct a `n x n` matrix where the first row is only `1`'s the second row is the calculated list in a row and the following rows are this list raised to power `i`, where `i=2,...,n`.

Example:

```
n=4; list={2,3,5,4};
m = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2,3,5,4}, {4, 9, 25, 16}, {8,27,125,64}};
```

Comment: @Kuba Maybe he means `i` should be a power of two from `1` to `n`?  That would fit with what he has.

Comment: Phytab, by "dynamic" do you mean that you want to use this function inside a [`Dynamic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic.html) expression, or do you just mean that the size of the matrix should change when you feed the function a different `n`?

Comment: The 4th row is indeed a mistake, thanks for that :)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion with Dynamic, I mean that the size of the matrix should change with n as you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

```
f[n_,list_] := Table[ list^k, {k,0,n-1} ]
```

so that `f[3,{2,3,4}]` produces `{{1,1,1},{2,3,4},{4,9,16}}`.

If `list` can contain zeros, use the following instead:

```
f[n_, list_] := 
 Table[If[k == 0, ConstantArray[1, Length@list], list^k], {k, 0, 
   n - 1}]
```

or, to avoid to have it do a check at every iteration,

```
f[n_, list_] := Join[{ConstantArray[1,Length@list]},Table[list^k,{k,1,n-1}]]
```

Comment: This one has problems if `list` has a zero in it.

Comment: @2012rcampion corrected

Comment: Since you know you're going to have exactly one `k == 0` every time, I would have done something like `Prepend[Table[list^k, {k, n}], ConstantArray[1, Length@list]]` to avoid the `If`.

Comment: I actually thought of doing it like that, but then found the code with the `If` more clear. But of course you are right it is useless to have it do the check every time

Comment: This is working, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
Manipulator[Dynamic[n], {2, 10,1}]
Dynamic[list2 = list^# & /@ Range[0, n-1]]
```